# Colorize PyLint Output?

Tags: python, pylint, colorize

Anyone have any tricks/techniques for colorizing PyLint output?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$ pylint --output-format=colorized
```

Try `$ pylint --help | less` for more useful tricks.

Comment: To be honest, it is a shame that pylint failed to allow environment variables to force colors in 2022. See https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3995

Answer (score 3):

If you feel up to [writing a Pygments lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/) then you could use [`pygmentize`](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/).